# How do I view a variable with set /p in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I don't know how to explain it, but i wanna do something like this:

```
@echo off
set test1=500
set test2=750
set /p view=
set show=%%view%%
echo %show%
pause
```

Basically I want to type in "test1" or "test2" and then the variable 'show' should set to %test1% (500) or %test2% (750), but it won't work for some reason.
It always shows '%view%'. It should show up as '500' or '750'. Any help?

PS: I'm sorry, but I am bad at explaining stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways:

```
call set show=%%%view%%%
```

or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set show=!%view%!
```

You may read full details about this management at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `IF` condition to get this done like below

```
@echo off
set test1=500
set test2=750
set /p view=
if /I "%view%"=="test1" (set show=%test1%)
if /I "%view%"=="test2" (set show=%test2%)
echo %show%
```

Comment: When I do that, it shows 'test1' or 'test2' instead of '500' or '750'.